# fork and signals problem with glob variables

Tags: c, linux, global-variables, signals, fork

I got this code from my lecturer and I ran into some troubles figuring out what is going on.
When I ran it on Linux The output was:

```
hello SIGUSR2
SIGUSR2: the value of glob is: 1
hello SIGUSR1
SIGUSR1: the value of glob is: 2
Line 54 is done
Line 48 is done
```

My questions are:

1.Why SIGUSR2 is executed before SIGUSR1?

2. How does the child part leaves the while loop?
   I thought that fork splits the program and its variables, global variables as well, thus glob would stay 0 in the child process and wouldn't be incremented to 2.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

int glob = 0;
void signal_hand(int sig) {
    int i, fd;
    signal(SIGUSR1, signal_hand);
    printf("hello SIGUSR1\n");
    glob++;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++);
    printf("SIGUSR1: the value of glob is: %d\n", glob);
    fd = open("usr1.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL | S_IRWXU | S_IXGRP);
    write(fd, "hello SIGUSR1 \n", 20);
    close(fd);
}

void signal_hand2(int sig) {
    int i, fd;
    signal(SIGUSR2, signal_hand2);
    printf("hello SIGUSR2\n");
    glob++;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++);
    printf("SIGUSR2: the value of glob is: %d\n", glob);
    fd = open("usr2.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL | S_IRWXU | S_IXGRP);
    write(fd, "hello SIGUSR2 \n", 20);
    close(fd);
}

int main(void) {
    pid_t my_pid;
    int status;
    signal(SIGUSR1, signal_hand);
    signal(SIGUSR2, signal_hand2);
    my_pid = fork();

    if (my_pid > 0) {
        kill(my_pid, SIGUSR1);

        kill(my_pid, SIGUSR2);
        wait(&status);
        printf("Line 48 is done\n");
    }

    if (my_pid == 0) {
        while(glob < 2);
        printf("Line 54 is done\n");
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Note that the Linux documentation on the function [`signal`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) does not recommend to use this function. You should use `sigaction` instead.

Comment: First, you can not safely call `printf()` in a signal handler.  Second, your usage of `open()` is wrong.  When called with the `O_CREAT` flag, `open()` takes three parameters, not two.

Comment: So because printf is not safe it means the functions calls are switched?

Comment: and any Idea about the second question?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: You are right that it is not safe to call `printf` in an **asynchronous** signal handler. But I believe it is safe to call it in a **synchronous** signal handler. According to the [documentation of the function `kill`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html), when a process is signalling itself only once, the function `kill` will not return until the signal has been "delivered". This probably means that the signal handler must have finished running before the function `kill` returns.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel There's no such thing as a synchronous signal handler.  And in this case, the `kill()` signal is actually being sent to the ***child*** process from the ***parent*** process since `fork()` returns `0` in the child process and the pid of the child process in the parent process.  `my_pid` is badly misnamed here.

Comment: @ShimonCohen, because `printf` is not async-signal-safe, yet is called in the context of a signal handler, the program's behavior is *undefined*.  That means that one cannot reason about the behavior of this program at all, at least not based on its source code alone.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: According to [this documenation on the ISO C function `signal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal), signals called as a result of calling `abort` or `raise` are not considered asynchronous signal handlers. According to [this documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/raise.3.html), the function `raise` is equivalent to `kill(getpid(), sig);`, However, you are right that in the case of the OP, it is asynchronous, because a child process is being signalled.

Comment: Moreover, even if the `printf` calls did not occur in signal handlers, they have undefined behavior because they do not satisfy other POSIX requirements about using different handles on the same open file description.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, as far as I can determine, neither POSIX nor C distinguishes between handling signals synchronously and asynchronously as far whether async-signal-safe functions may be called.  See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03, for example.  If you have documentation to support your claim to the contrary then I would be interested to see it.

Comment: `while(glob < 2);` could be optimised out without `volatile`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Absent platform-specific guarantees, you can't call ***any*** library functions from within a signal handler.  Per [C11 footnote 188](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."   This is no platform-specific guarantee that it's safe to call `printf()` from a signal handler.  On any platform.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Note that the footnote you refer to uses the phrase "in general", not "always". As far as I can tell, if the signal handler is called in a synchronous manner using `abort` or `raise` (§7.14.1.1 ¶5) and the program is not multithreaded (§7.14.1.1 ¶7), then reentrancy should not be an issue, so §7.1.4 ¶4 (which refers to your footnote) is not relevant.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: In the link you posted, the sentence starting with `If the process is multi-threaded,` states that if the signal handler is not called in a synchronous manner (not using `abort`, `raise`, `kill`, `pthread_kill` or `sigqueue` by the same process) and it calls any library functions besides those listed as `async-signal-safe`, then the behavior is undefined. This implies that the behavior is defined if the signal handler is called in a synchronous manner.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, that provision excepts signals received by a single-threaded process that were generated as a result of that process calling certain functions.  That has nothing to do with *handling* signals synchronously (e.g. by calling `sigsuspend()`), and signals themselves are not categorized into synchronous and asynchronous.  All that is anyway irrelevant to the present question, because the signals in question do not fall under the exception you point out.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I have already conceded in a previous comment that in OP's case, the signal handler is being called asynchronously.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Regarding your statement that the referenced sentence has nothing to do with handling signals synchronously, I disagree. When using the functions `abort`, `raise`, `kill`, `pthread_kill` or `sigqueue` in a single-threaded program to signal itself, these functions are all guaranteed to not return before the signal has been handled, assuming no other signals are being handled asynchronously or are queued to do so. Therefore, in my opinion, it is appropriate to describe this as handling signals "synchronously".

Comment: @AndreasWenzel You have completely missed the entire purpose of [footnote 188](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188). It explicitly states that it is unsafe to call ***any*** C library function because of [7.1.4p4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p4): "The functions in the standard library are not guaranteed to be reentrant and may modify objects with static or thread storage duration."  At best, you are promoting bug-prone code.  At worst, you are pushing the limits of the C standard and risking undefined behavior.  My standards are higher than both.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like everything is as to be expected.

First the *parent* program `fork`s and the sends the `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` signals to the just created *child*.

The *parent* then waits for the *child* to finish.

The *child* handles both signals, thus incrementing (its) `glob` twice, from 0 to 1 to 2.

As for the order the signals are processed, it is not specified in which order two signals available at the same time are to be handled, so either order is correct.

And, as already mentioned in the comments, what you can do in a (asynchrounous) signal handler (what you have here) is limited. `printf` is not part of that. So the program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Because the parent already has a pid. It only needs to know the pid of its newborn child.

Comment: *thus incrementing (its) glob twice, from 0 to 1 to 2*  Maybe, maybe not.  [`glob` is not `volatile sig_atomic_t`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p5): "When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a signal, the values of objects that are neither lock-free atomic objects nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t are unspecified, as is the state of the floating-point environment. The value of any object modified by the handler that is neither a lock-free atomic object nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t becomes indeterminate when the handler exits ..."

Comment: @AndrewHenle, the standard indeed does not guarantee that it works, for good reason. But here it just happens to work (but that does not make it correct)